# How to find radius of convergence of Power series with recurrence relation containing 2 terms?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have following ODE problem

$(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+y/x=0$

The power series solution of that ODE near x=1 is

$y_{k+2}=-[\frac{(2k+1)(k+1)y_{k+1}+(k^2+1)y_k}{(k+2)(k+1)}]$

I have to find Radius of Convergence.

As $k\to \infty$

$y_{k+2}=-[\frac{2y_{k+1}+y_k}{1}]$

$\frac{y_{k+2}}{y_{k+1}}=-2-\frac{y_{k}}{y_{k+1}}$

Let $l=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{y_{k+2}}{y_{k+1}}$
....My Assumption Limit exist and equals to ROC

then 
$l=-2-1/l$

Solving this I get $|l|=1$

So ROC is 1

Is this solution Mathematically Look correct?
Please give me a suggestion

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: For large $k$ you get $y_{k+2}=-\frac13y_{k+1}$ plus some small perturbation. One would thus expect a radius of convergence of $3$.

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir . I missed that observation

Comment: @LutzL Dear Sir I used your method to solve another problem That I have edited. Please, Can you give me suggestion regarding solution...

Comment: This is not exactly a proof, more a calculation of the limit under the assumption that it exists. // Also, this is an Euler-Cauchy equation with characteristic polynomial $0=m(m-1)+m+1=m^2+1$ leading to a general solution $y(x)=C_1\cos(\ln|x|)+C_2\sin(\ln|x|)$ so that indeed the radius of convergence around $x=1$ is $R=1$.

Comment: Thanks for providing me new way to tackle problem. I had not thought like this earlier....Is there any way to directly calculate radius of convergence from power series without explicitly finding root like earlier example?